# CSS not working in IE6-7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm facing a prob with my `CSS` in `IE7` and `IE6`. The biggest problem is that in one of my page the `CSS` is not loading at all in `IE 7,6`.

When I use the following code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
[if lt IE 7] <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> [endif]
[if IE 7]  <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> [endif]
[if IE 8]    <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> [endif]
[if IE 9]    <html class="ie9" lang="en"> [endif]
[if gt IE 9] <html lang="en"> [endif]
```

The `CSS` is getting loaded, but then, while running the website on chrome or `Firefox` the above codes of line are also printed. However no line is printed while using `IE` and the `CSS` is working fine.

Also when I use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

The CSS does not loads again in IE. What should I do.?

I hope my question is clear to you. Please Help.

Comment: Why are you supporting IE6 and 7?  Even Microsoft no longer supports these.  Unless you have a very good reason, you are making a lot of unnecessary work for yourself.

Comment: Do you have an example of your page and your css file? The snippet doesn't tell us much about your problem.

Comment: @PeterWooster - I Know but many of my clients are still using IE 7. Even I had the exact question for them.. :P

Comment: Try and change your bottom line (in the second code snippet) to "<!--[if gt IE 9]> <html lang="en"> <![endif]-->"

Comment: @wildandjam - which 'normal' browser gets the <html>tag then, if they are all commented out?

Comment: @chrona - http://www.indiareads.com/book/9780006512257/the-eleventh-commandment/jeffrey-archer/fiction-general/

visit this link. If you open the site in chrome ull see a line written on top. I wrote that for IE7. If I remove that line from my code, the css no longer works on IE6 or 7.

Comment: @user3514339 - You are using html before you define your <!DOCTYPE html>, the doctype should always be the first part in your .html file.

Comment: @chrona - it wasn't meant as a complete fix, just one fix of many. Until there is more information, difficult to divulge the real issue.

Comment: 'CSS not working in IE6-7' is not a question, more an explanation of most of the work done by web developers in the last 12 years

Comment: I hope that really NO ONE uses IE6 today, and you can forget that browser... IE7 is not so bad - compared to predecessor... :)

Comment: Fire the client or charge double for the aggregation that supporting this antique browser is going to cause you.  this is only the start of your problems.

Comment: Others have suggested dropping support. While I agree that IE6/7 support is not necessary for a modern website, I don't think that the basis for dropping support should be because you can't get a particular set of IE Conditional Comments to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You file starts with this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(add)
{       
var pin;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    pin=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {
    pin= new ActiveXobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  url=add;
pin.open("GET",url,true);
pin.send();
}
</script>
</head>

</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html lang="en">
…
```

As you are ending the file before it even starts, you are triggering [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) in IE7 and below. Your file should start like the 2nd snippet you've posted.

Comment: hey thanks ill see that. actually i've imported a file before <!doctype html> so its showing <html> before it. thanks for the help.... (Y)